# Serializing Discriminated Union in F# using FSharpLu - How do i hide property name from Discriminated Union Types?

Tags: serialization, f#, discriminated-union

i am new to F#, and have a task to serialize a Discriminated Union. That in itself is simple, you can serialize it, and you'll get a nice (ugly) case: fields: set of nodes.

Using the Compact Serializer from FSharpLu (https://github.com/Microsoft/fsharplu) we can get this down to a more manageable format, without Case: Field: nodes.
However, instead, we get the name of the Type that was serialized as the nodes name. This is not wanted.

If i have a types such as:

```
type Entry = {
    id: string
    foo: int
    bar: string
}

type Group = {
    id: string
    entryList: Entry seq
}

type EntryOrGroup =
 | Entry of Entry
 | Group of Group
```

In the output, an array of EntryOrGroup, i would get each node decorated with its type name, which i do not want.

Is there a way to hide the type name? but still output the desired json nodes?

**EDIT:**
Example of current output:

```
[
    {
        Group: {
            id: "firstEntry",
            entryList: [
                {
                id: "foobar",
                foo: 12,
                bar: "something"
                },
                {
                id: "barfoo",
                foo: 13,
                bar: "somethingElse"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
        Entry: {
            id: "foofoobar",
            foo: 16,
            bar: "notSomething"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Example of Desired Output:

```
[
    {
        {
            id: "firstEntry",
            entryList: [
                {
                id: "foobar",
                foo: 12,
                bar: "something"
                },
                {
                id: "barfoo",
                foo: 13,
                bar: "somethingElse"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            {
            id: "foofoobar",
            foo: 16,
            bar: "notSomething"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

**Edit2:** 
I forked the FSharpLu repo, and changed the Compact Serializer to no longer write the start of objects and the end of objects in a Discriminated Union. This achieves the result i'm looking for. However, i don't know right now how i can implement that in my work... Is a forked repo too much to maintain, is it worth it for this tiny change? Hmm...

Changes were from [Line 146 of Compact.fs](https://github.com/Microsoft/fsharplu/blob/master/FSharpLu.Json/Compact.fs#L146):
From:

```
        else
        let case, fields = getUnionFields value

        match fields with
        // Field-less union case
        | [||] -> writer.WriteValue(convertName case.Name)
        // Case with single field
        | [|onefield|] ->
            writer.WriteStartObject()
            writer.WritePropertyName(convertName case.Name)
            serializer.Serialize(writer, onefield)
            writer.WriteEndObject()
        // Case with list of fields
        | _ ->
            writer.WriteStartObject()
            writer.WritePropertyName(convertName case.Name)
            serializer.Serialize(writer, fields)
            writer.WriteEndObject()
```

To:

```
        else
        let case, fields = getUnionFields value

        match fields with
        // Field-less union case
        | [||] -> writer.WriteValue(convertName case.Name)
        // Case with single field
        | [|onefield|] ->
            serializer.Serialize(writer, onefield)
        // Case with list of fields
        | _ ->
            writer.WritePropertyName(convertName case.Name)
            serializer.Serialize(writer, fields)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are few alternatives that you can consider if you don't want to write/maintain custom Json.NET converter:

**1. Use some other serialization library**

Two alternatives that give you more control how data is serialized:

1. [Thoth.Json.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Thoth.Json.Net/)
2. [Chiron](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Chiron/7.0.0-beta-180105)

**2. Use data transfer objects that are serialized as you want**

```
    type EntryOrGroupDTO = {
        id: string
        foo: int option
        bar: string option
        entryList: Entry seq option
    }

    let dtoData =
        data
        |> Array.map (fun entryOrGroup ->
            match entryOrGroup with
            | Entry entry ->
                { id = entry.id
                  foo = Some entry.foo
                  bar = Some entry.bar
                  entryList = None }
            | Group group ->
                { id = group.id
                  foo = None
                  bar = None
                  entryList = Some group.entryList })

    let settings =
        JsonSerializerSettings(
            NullValueHandling=NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            Converters=[|CompactUnionJsonConverter()|]
        )

    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dtoData, Formatting.Indented, settings)
```

**3. Unwarp and box**

```
    let objData =
        data
        |> Array.map (fun entryOrGroup ->
            match entryOrGroup with
            | Entry entry -> box entry
            | Group group -> box group)


    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objData, Formatting.Indented)
```

Comment: In the end for speed we forked the library with the changes we want. This will however be changed to DTO and a normal serializer after Christmas. Thanks for the help!